# Can I nest the IF function inside of the Filter Function?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, filterfunction

Can I nest the IF or any other function inside of the FILTER function to return maybe 1 instead of GBP in column J and return LON instead of LONDON in column B?[image]

Comment: Yes, you can :-)

Comment: Thanks, this one works
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(IF(A:E="GBP",1,A:E),(A:A="MS")*(E:E<>0)),1,2,3,4,5)
I was not meant to return column B so that's why but forgot to exclude it.

So I can return the column that includes GBP as 1 then can I also add another column to it so return Column D as 1 and return column B as just LON?

Comment: Please try to avoid asking the same question twice [Can I nest the IF or any other function inside of the Filter Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77344735/can-i-nest-the-if-or-any-other-function-inside-of-the-filter-function)

Comment: It has no responses, I asked another follow up question on this current thread but didn't get a response so posted another question and yeah sure thing, my bad

Comment: You'd be better off manipulating the results of `FILTER()` rather than the entire data set. A proper answer would involve isolating the individual columns, but a quick answer could be something like: `=LET(arr,FILTER(A:E,(A:A="MS")*(E:E<>0)),SWITCH(arr,"GBP",1,"LONDON","LON",arr))`. Be aware, though, this is searching across all columns.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on isolating the individual columns, please?

Comment: @IlyasEsa You can use `INDEX()` to identify the columns to manipulate, then stitch everything back together with `HSTACK()` wrapped in `CHOOSECOLS()` to set the desired column order. For example: `=LET(arr,FILTER(A:E,(A:A="MS")*(E:E<>0)),add,LEFT(INDEX(arr,,2),3),cur,SWITCH(INDEX(arr,,4),"GBP",1,"EUR",2,"USD",3),CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(arr,add,cur),1,6,3,7,5))`. **Note:** I included additional currencies here simply to illustrate how `SWITCH()` can be used; also, for the address column, I just used `LEFT()` to return the first 3 letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments above, it would be more efficient to manipulate the results of the `FILTER()` function by nesting it inside of another function, rather than attempting to manipulate the entire data set. One such function that would work in this situation is the `SWITCH()` function:

```
=LET(
arr, FILTER(A2:E1000, (A2:A1000="MS")*(E2:E1000<>0)),
SWITCH(arr, "GBP", 1, "LONDON", "LON", arr))
```

`SWITCH()` looks at each value in the filtered array and replaces any matching values found with their corresponding results. Matching values and results are entered in pairs and can include up to 126 pairs in total. The final optional argument is the default value to be returned if no match is found, which in this case is the original value present in the filtered array. Also, `SWITCH()` only performs an exact match, so you can't use wildcards or comparison operators.

The above-mentioned formula is the quick and easy method, which works with the sample data you provided; however, it could be prone to errors if "GBP" and/or "LONDON" are present in more than one column. Furthermore, if you're actual data set contains multiple city names in the "Address" column (ie: Birmingham, Glasgow, Liverpool, etc.), managing the list of values and their corresponding results within `SWITCH()` can become quite cumbersome. As such, it would be more appropriate to identify the specific columns in the filtered array that you wish to manipulate and perform the applicable action on each individual column:

```
=LET(
arr, FILTER(A2:E1000, (A2:A1000="MS")*(E2:E1000<>0)),
add, LEFT(INDEX(arr,,2), 3),
cur, SWITCH(INDEX(arr,,4), "GBP", 1, "EUR", 2, "USD", 3),
CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(arr, add, cur), 1, 6, 3, 7, 5))
```

In this example, `INDEX()` was used to identify the entire "Address" column by omitting the *row_num* argument and setting the *column_num* to **2**, and `LEFT()` was used to simply return the first 3 letters of each value. The "Currency" column was identified in the same manner with *column_num* **4**, and `SWITCH()` was used to replace the currency codes with a numeric value. This method works fine if your data set only contains a limited number of currency codes. I didn't specify the final default value argument in this case, so `SWITCH()` will return `#N/A` if a new code is present (ie: "CAD"), and you'll know the formula needs to be updated with an additional pair of values and results.

`HSTACK()` is then used to create a new array consisting of the filtered array, plus the new "add" and "cur" columns (7 columns in total), and `CHOOSECOLS()` is used to replace the original column 2 with the new column 6, as well as 4 with 7. That's it!

On a side note, I'm not a fan of using entire column references like `A:E`, `A:A` and `E:E` as this will significantly reduce the overall performance of the workbook (you'll likely notice a lag or hesitation when inputting new values in the referenced columns). Structured tables are ideal because the column references are dynamic and expand automatically when new records are added. However, if you prefer standard range references, I highly recommend using a ***reasonable*** number of rows that extends far enough below your existing data to allow for growth. For example: if your dealing with only a few hundred rows of data, `A2:E1000`, `A2:A1000` and `E2:E1000` would be adequate, and it's far more efficient than `A1:E1048576` (which is what `A:E` is referencing).

Cheers!